# Передать в класс функцию для выполнения из класса

Tags: java, callback

Не пинайте сильно новичка в java.
Мне нужно реализовать такой функционал:
Есть свой класс myOkHttpClient в нем обрабатывается ответ от сервера по событию onResponse()
Мне нужно чтобы по получению ответа передать этот ответ назад в место вызова.
Т.е. что-то типа такого:

```
myOkHttpClient myClient = new myOkHttpClient(MainActivity.this, SERVER_URL);
myClient.getResponse((response) -> {
// сделать что-то с response
});

public class myOkHttpClient {
// много кода
 public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
 // тут вернуть response назад в место вызова
 }
}
```

Полагаю, что подход, который можно реализовать через callback в JS тут неприменим.
Направьте пожалуйста в нужно направлении, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подход с использованием callback-a применим. Можно, например, передать его в конструктор `myOkHttpClient` и сохранить в поле:

```
private final Consumer<Response> responseHandler;

public myOkHttpClient(Consumer<Response> responseHandler)
{
    this.responseHandler = responseHandler;
}
```

после чего вызвать в методе `onResponse`:

```
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException
{
    responseHandler.accept(response);
}
```

---

Можно пойти и другим путём, особенно если нужно выполнять responseHandler в потоке, отличном от потока, в котором вызывается onResponse. Для этого в клиенте должен быть метод отправки запроса (sendRequest), а `Call` или `Response` должны уметь хранить контекст сделанного запроса

Если всё так, то можно в sendRequest генерировать id запроса (requestId), отдавать его в качестве результата вызова метода, а в onResponse складывать response в `HashMap<Integer, Response> requestIdToResponse`. Во внешнем же коде нужно будет периодически поллить клиент на предмет появления response-a по заданному requestId